# SELECT vs COPY (SELECT) TO STDOUT

Tags: postgresql, select, performance, copy, bulkcopy, postgresql-performance

I need to read more rows than fit in memory, resonably fast. I see two options:

- `SELECT ...` where my bindings use a cursor to stream the rows;
- `COPY (SELECT ...) TO STDOUT (FORMAT binary)` where my bindings decode the binary format into rows.

What are the theoretical differences in performance and behaviour between the above approaches, or are they effectively identical?

Comment: I think we need more context here: what do you want to do with your data ? (changing them, displaying them, sending them?)

Comment: Why use the binary format?

Answer (score 2):

As far as the server and the network protocol are concerned, the result of a query and the binary COPY protocol are pretty much identical.

So you would choose COPY only if your client's PG library handles it better in your situation.